# How to change UITextField textColor when click on Button in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've created custom UITextField as follow

```
@IBInspectable var hasError: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        self.borderColor = hasError ? .red: .black
        self.textColor = hasError ? .red : .black
    }
}
```

and I did as follow when I click on Button and then, hide keyboard and change UITextField textColor to red after that.

```
@IBAction func checkAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {   
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myTextField.hasError = true
    }
}
```

Above code is not working as textColor not changed to be red when `checkAction` action called. Surprisingly, when I've added that line `_ = myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` and run it again, code is working. My question is please let me know how could I change UITextField color to red by not adding Keyboard `_ = myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` in that function. Thanks.

Comment: Just place that line after change color code. And try again.

Comment: I tried it. And nothing wrong. Has or not the line `_ = myTextField.resignFirstResponder()`, it changed the text's color

Comment: It should work. Maybe you are changing the textColor back to black in some delegate. ResignResponder will trigger the shouldEnd/End Editing delegate

Comment: @aBilal17 not working though.

Comment: @QuocNguyen when I've removed that line, it's working.

Comment: @ppshein I kept the `resignFirstResponder` line, and it worked too.I think the problem is not that line

Comment: @QuocNguyen my bad, sorry. I've edited my question. I need to add `becomeFirstResponder` in order to change text to red color.

Comment: @aBilal17 I've edit question, sorry.

Comment: @ppshein the code still work well. You can create a simple project for testing it. I think the problem's not here.

Comment: @QuocNguyen is right sample is working perfectly.